# How to open .mov format video in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

```
  <video width="400" controls autoplay>
      <source src="./asset1.mov" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

This is my code, it doesn't play in all browsers.
I want to play video in mov format in all browsers.

Comment: Not all browsers/OSs support mov playback, so this isn't possible https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#quicktime

Comment: Convert MOV to MP4. If the video codecs is H264 and the audio is AAC then you can just quick copy (not re-encode ) the a/v data across (a tool like FFmpeg or HandBrake can do it)